# I Try to validate data by database to login by use Bootsrap model and ajax with PHP but It's not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Firstly sorry for the poor English.
I Need To validate data from the database using PHP with the bootstrap model and ajax. I try to do this like this:

I Create an **index.php** file and **action.php** file.
Then use ajax and I try to load **action.php** from action.php file I try to validate my login details.

```
<?php   
 session_start();  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Make Login Form by Using Bootstrap Modal with PHP Ajax Jquery</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
           </head>  
      <body>  
           <br/>  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Make Login Form by Using Bootstrap Modal with PHP Ajax Jquery</h3><br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <?php  
                if(isset($_SESSION['username']))  
                {  
                ?>  
                <div align="center">  
                     <h1>Welcome - <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h1><br />  
                     <a href="#" id="logout">Logout</a>  
                </div>  
                <?php  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                ?>  
                <div align="center">  
                     <button type="button" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>  
                </div>  
                <?php  
                }  
                ?>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
   <!-- Modal content-->  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <label>Username</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Password</label>  
                     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <button type="button" name="login_button" id="login_button" class="btn btn-warning">Login</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#login_button').click(function(){  
           var username = $('#username').val();  
           var password = $('#password').val();  
           if(username != '' && password != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"action.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data: {username:username, password:password},  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          //alert(data);  
                          if(data == 'No')  
                          {  
                               alert("Wrong Data");  
                          }  
                          else  
                          {  
                               $('#loginModal').hide();  
                               location.reload();  
                          }  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                alert("Both Fields are required");  
           }  
      });  
      $('#logout').click(function(){  
           var action = "logout";  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"action.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{action:action},  
                success:function()  
                {  
                     location.reload();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>  

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**action.php file**

```
<?php   
 session_start();  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Make Login Form by Using Bootstrap Modal with PHP Ajax Jquery</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
           </head>  
      <body>  
           <br/>  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Make Login Form by Using Bootstrap Modal with PHP Ajax Jquery</h3><br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <?php  
                if(isset($_SESSION['username']))  
                {  
                ?>  
                <div align="center">  
                     <h1>Welcome - <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h1><br />  
                     <a href="#" id="logout">Logout</a>  
                </div>  
                <?php  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                ?>  
                <div align="center">  
                     <button type="button" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>  
                </div>  
                <?php  
                }  
                ?>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
   <!-- Modal content-->  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <label>Username</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Password</label>  
                     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <button type="button" name="login_button" id="login_button" class="btn btn-warning">Login</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#login_button').click(function(){  
           var username = $('#username').val();  
           var password = $('#password').val();  
           if(username != '' && password != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"action.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data: {username:username, password:password},  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          //alert(data);  
                          if(data == 'No')  
                          {  
                               alert("Wrong Data");  
                          }  
                          else  
                          {  
                               $('#loginModal').hide();  
                               location.reload();  
                          }  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                alert("Both Fields are required");  
           }  
      });  
      $('#logout').click(function(){  
           var action = "logout";  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"action.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{action:action},  
                success:function()  
                {  
                     location.reload();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>  

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**But there is no error and login button Not Working.**
I Need to know What's the error? Thank you.
[image: login image]

**Update:**
Include console error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at (index):48

[image: connsole error]

Comment: Can you open the dev console to see if there's an error? Ctrl+Shift+J then go to console tab.

Comment: Please include your action.php as well.

Comment: @JerdineSabio Question updates with console error

Comment: @JerdineSabio action.php file already added

Comment: your jquery cdn execute after you script... so put cdns before your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the jquery CDN to uncompressed version, the slim version with bootstrap excludes ajax [Related Information](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AselaBro One more thing i did notice at first, included the JQuery CDN before the JQuery script

Comment: It's Working! Thanks a lot